# Launch activity from ActivityResultLauncher result

Tags: java, android

I am launching an activity from MainActivity using the following launcher:

```
Button someButton = findViewById(R.id.some_button);
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> someActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
    new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
    new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
            if (result.getResultCode() == 1) {
                Intent data = result.getData();
                SomeClass obj = (obj) data.getSerializableExtra("Object");
                openOtherActivity(obj);
            }
        }
    }
);

someButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent someIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SomeActivity.class);
        someActivityResultLauncher.launch(someIntent);
    }
});
```

After launching someActivity, i am getting a response object from it. Then i want to launch another activity and pass the response object as input by calling openOtherActivity(obj). The second activity launcher goes like this:

```
public void openOtherActivity(SomeClass obj){
    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> otherActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                if (result.getResultCode() == 1) {
                    //do nothing
                }
            }
        }
    );
    Intent profileIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OtherActivity.class);
    otherIntent.putExtra("Object", obj);
    otherActivityResultLauncher.launch(otherIntent);
}
```

After testing the above, the following error occurs while calling the openOtherActivity().

```
MainActivity@88a859c is attempting to register while current state is STARTED. LifecycleOwners must call register before they are STARTED.
```

Comment: Put the code outside that function. Registrate both at the same time. Same place.

Comment: This works indeed, thanks. But it doesn't look like a good coding practice because i launch 2 activities in the same place (function). Any way it will work in a seperate function?

Comment: Try running the function on the main thread if you want it your way.  Also, the simplest solution is generally preferred so +1 blackapps!  It's much more readable, less convoluted, and shrinks code by 2 lines!  Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: @BigBeef the activities i launch perform http requests so i can't launch them on the main thread. There has to be a more elegant way of activity management that i am unaware of, bundling launchers together seems bad code to me.

Comment: Right, so I would launch the activities on the main thread after the success.  Not to say your code isn't good looking, but what is bad code?  When you call the runOnUIThread(()->{//code});, that solution, to me, is ugly, which is what I'm suggesting you do.  Let us know how it goes!